# Read result of XSL Transformation with StAX in a streaming mode

Tags: java, xml, xslt, stax

My use case is:

- XML `File` as input
- Needs to be transformed with XSLT (using Java 8 build-in XSLT processor)
- Process the `Result` with a `XMLStreamReader` (using Java 8 build-in StAX implementation)

I want to do this in a "streaming mode" (so *not* writing the output of the XSL Transformation to a File and than parsing it by the XMLStreamReader).

Is this possible? If so, how? I can only find SAX-based examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not possible. Most XSLT engines write the result "tree" in push mode, so you can skip the creating of a physical tree by accepting events as they occur, but if you want to get the result in pull mode you're going to need to run the transformation in one thread and read the results in another thread, using something like a BlockingQueue to communicate the events from on thread to another. Saxon has internal mechanisms to handle push-pull conflicts using multiple threads in this way, but only at item level, not at event level, and this isn't much use to you because the whole result tree is one item. So the basic answer is, the only way I can see to do what you want is to write a multi-threaded SAX-to-StAX converter, which is a tricky bit of Java coding.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a transform the XSLT processor needs to build its result within the transform call.

It is easy to see that the engine can write the result to a **stream**, or build up a **DOM** (or any other in memory structure), or call a **SAXHandler**.

But how should the engine directly accept and *invoke* a XMLStreamReader which has a different programming model than a callback oriented SAX Handler?

But you could create a DOM tree as result of the transformation. Given the DOM it is possible to create a `DOMXmlStreamReader` which iterates over the DOM and emits Stax tokens. But I don't know if such an implementation exists.

Comment: I do understand that the XSLT processor cannot directly call the reader (push <-> pull). Building an intermediate DOM tree, does not seem efficient for me (at least, not more efficient than a using File or byte buffer). However, i was more thinking of a `SAX2StaxStream` But yeah, that seems impossible. So the short answer is: "This is not possible"?

Comment: Building up an intermediary in-memory representation like a DOM allows you to skip the parsing step, so it can be more efficient than writing the transform result to a file/buffer and parse the file/buffer. On the other hand also depends on the size of the DOM and the amount of available memory. Anyway an intermediary DOM is no longer a pure-streaming solution. So, yes, imho it is not possible.